# How to run SQL code on a subsets of data (Grouped By without aggregation)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, data-conversion

I'm doing some data conversion and I'm required to group my data and perform some logical code on each group. For the example below, I want to group by customer name and customer ID and anytime this group contains the source system as SAP, i want to survive that row and not the others. I've been playing around with row_number() over partition by to group my data but I'm finding it difficult to do what I need to do unless I can run some logic on a group basis. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Source System    Customer_ID  Customer_Name Survivor 
------------------------------------------------------ 
SAP              1               Walmart         Y  
Oracle           1               Walmart         N  
Oracle           1               Walmart         N  
Oracle           1               Walmart         N  
Oracle           2               Target          Y  
Oracle           2               Target          N  
Oracle           2               Target          N
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to run [Transact SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) on an Oracle database?

Comment: Oops, i meant PL/SQL. Updated title. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following matches your expected output for survivor, but I am not sure of your logic for customer 2 as all rows seem the same:

```
SELECT  "Source System",
        "Customer ID",
        "Customer Name",
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Customer ID" 
                                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN "Source System" = 'SAP' 
                                                THEN 0 
                                                ELSE 1 
                                            END)
                             = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Survivor"
FROM    T
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34bd8/2)**

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That is exactly what i was looking for. Logic for customer 2 wasn't clear in my example, apologies.